# Compile EJS templates to HTML in separate folder

Tags: gulp, ejs

I need to export my ejs templates to html files in a separate "dist" folder at the root of my project. I do have gulp-ejs installed and have the following setup in my gulpfile.js, but it is not creating the folder and compiling the html files to it:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cssbeautify = require('gulp-cssbeautify'),
    ejs = require('gulp-ejs');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/')
    );
});

gulp.task('css', function(){
  return gulp.src('./styles/*.css')
    .pipe(cssbeautify({
      indent: ' ',
      openbrace: 'end-of-line',
      autosemicolon: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/'));
});

gulp.task('ejs', function(){
  return gulp.src('./views/pages/*.ejs')<----SHOULD GRAB ALL EJS PAGES
   .pipe(ejs({}, {ext:'.html'})) <-----ADD EXTENSION OF .HTML
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')) <-----AND EXPORT THEM TO THE DIST FOLDER
});

//Watch
gulp.task('default', function(){
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss',['styles','css','ejs']);
});
```

Also, my directory structure is as follows:

```
-css
-node_modules
-routes
-sass
-views
  |-pages
    |-about.ejs
    |-index.ejs
  |-partials
    |-head.ejs
    |-nav.ejs

 -gulpfile.js
 -package.json
 -server.js
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add another {} to ejs parameters.

`ejs(data,option,settings)`

```
gulp.task('ejs', function(){
  return gulp.src('./views/pages/*.ejs')<----SHOULD GRAB ALL EJS PAGES
   .pipe(ejs({},{}, {ext:'.html'})) <-----ADD EXTENSION OF .HTML
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')) <-----AND EXPORT THEM TO THE DIST FOLDER
});
```

This is how I do it and it works for me. (using gulp-ejs 3.0.0)

https://github.com/mde/ejs & https://github.com/rogeriopvl/gulp-ejs